# How to play DM2 videos on Ubuntu?

Tags: video, codecs

I'm having problems on trying play ".dm2" videos on Ubuntu 13.10.

The only player that opens this files was SMPlayer, but without image and the sound is a mess...

Any ideas ?!

Comment: Can you tell us where the .dm2 files came from? The only thing I can think of is the demo files for games such as Quake but since you say you get some sound playback in SMPlayer I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe you could install the "mediainfo" package and use that to find out the codecs used in the file - if it *is* a video file that should show it. But if as I suspected it's a game demo/replay file then you'd need to play it back through the game.

Comment: Hi @neon_overload the files came from that [portal](http://www.devmedia.com.br/curso/curso-de-gerenciamento-de-servidores-linux/369). I'll try "mediainfo" then.
Thaks one more time !!

Comment: Try "mediainfo" then.  It's possible that it's an existing format but just with a non-standard file extension.  It looks like the software that created/plays it is Brazilian.  Maybe it's a non-standard format and requires their player.

Comment: I think it is... There's a page indicating that the player (and probably the videos too) are encrypted for copyrights reasons. I think that is nonsense since only subscribers can download the files and anyone can use a screencast while playing the videos. But...
Thanks again @neon_overload

Comment: The output on mediainfo was:

AVI: 18.1 MiB, 23mn 9s --- Overall bit rate: 109Kbps --- Video: 48.1Kbps, 1280*720(16:9), at 5.000 fps, TechSmith --- Audio: 48.0 Kbps, 16.0 KHz, 2 channels, MPEG Audio (MP3)

Comment: Is there any way to install "camtasia vfw working TechSmith Camtasia Screen Codec [tsccvid.dll]" on SMPlayer without have to recompile it !?

Comment: I've added a new answer, check it out. I don't know of any way to use VFW (video for Windows) codecs on Linux, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> The output on mediainfo was: AVI: 18.1 MiB, 23mn 9s --- Overall bit rate: 109Kbps --- Video: 48.1Kbps, 1280*720(16:9), at 5.000 fps, TechSmith --- Audio: 48.0 Kbps, 16.0 KHz, 2 channels, MPEG Audio (MP3)

This indicates that they are ordinary AVI files (seemingly not "encrypted") but using the TSCC (Techsmith) codec for video and MP3 codec for audio.

Just about any player can play MP3 audio so the audio should play fine. However, poor or incomplete support for the TSCC video codec could cause the video not to show and may even cause the audio to stutter due to timing issues.

Anyway, if any open source player is going to be ahead of the curve in supporting an obscure codec it'll be VLC.  Try installing that and see how you go.

[At least this forum thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=86991) seems to indicate that the VLC player for Linux should have TSCC codec support built-in, but then there are other forum threads that say it's unreliable. Worth a try.